# printf not printing anything when the program is executed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int n;

int main()
{
    printf("Input the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    
    int array[n]; // Creating Integer of size N.
    printf("Enter %d Integers\n",n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]); // Storing values
    };
};
    
int LargestElementFunct()
{
    int array[0];
    int max=array[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if (array[i]>max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum = %d", max);
};
```

It is taking all thew inputs correctly but not displaying anything through `printf`. I am a bit new into this so please help me in this regard.

Comment: `LargestElementFunct` is never called.

Comment: When you have, add a newline to the output or `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: The `array` declared in `main` is **not** the same as the `array` (wrongly) declared in the never called `LargestElementFunct`. Did they already teach you how to call and pass parameters to a function? Are you familiar with the the concept of *scope* of a variable?

Comment: Rethink *naming* things. Choose names telling what something is good for - `values`, `largestElement()`. Consider leaving comments in the code what some piece of it is there for where that isn't *blatantly* obvious (like *what is this whole program good for?*).

Comment: (Revisit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need. The `array` variable you are declaring in `main()` cannot be accessed anywhere outside the `{}` of `main()`. This is called the scope of the variable. On the other hand `n` is a global variable, it is outside all the `{}` so it can be accessed anywhere. All other variables within `{}` are local variables and cannot be accessed outside the `{}`. `LargestElementFunct` cannot access your `array` in `main()`. You need to pass this `array` from `main` to `LargestElementFunct` to be able to use `array` there like this: `LargestElementFunct(array)` You have to call a function to execute it. `LargestElementFunc` is never called in `main` so your `printf` never executes. Also, `LargestElementFunct` has an `int` return type. So you have to return the `max` value. The thing is same with `max` too, it cannot be accessed in main so you have to return it from `LargestElementFunct` using the `return` statement at the end. Remember, input for a function is given through parameters, and output is passed to the caller using `return` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int LargestElementFunc(int[]);    
int n;

int main()
{
    printf("Input the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    
    int array[n]; // Creating Integer of size N.
    printf("Enter %d Integers\n",n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]); // Storing values
    }
    printf("%d", LargestElementFunct(array));
};
    
int LargestElementFunct(int array[])
{
    int max=array[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if (array[i]>max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
};
```

Comment: but now it gives an error : 'LargestElementFunct' cannot be used as a function,

Comment: @ahmedahmed It's because you need to *declare* (or define) the function [before](https://godbolt.org/z/b7zo79MeG) using it.

Comment: @ahmedahmed It is because I did not include the prototype for `LargestElementFunct()` before `main()`. I've added it now. That should fix it